# Is there a bug in this code example from "Beginning JavaScript with DOM Scripting and Ajax" or I am missing something?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, event-bubbling

I'm reading a book called "Beginning JavaScript with DOM Scripting and Ajax" (2006)

On [Page 168/139](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7pTviyp3SZYC&lpg=PA139&ots=0broVbH2ID&dq=if%28window.event%20&&%20window.event.cancelBubble%29&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q=if%28window.event%20&&%20window.event.cancelBubble%29&f=false) it offers some example code, a `stopBubble` function, which promises to prevent an event from propagating in both IE and DOM-2 compliant browsers:

```
stopBubble:function(e){
  if(window.event && window.event.cancelBubble){
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
  if (e && e.stopPropagation){
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Since the [cancelBubble property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a boolean property that defaults to false, I am wondering how we will ever reach the line where `cancelBubble` is set to `true` without it already being `true`. In other words that condition seems pointless.

I would not call myself an expert on JavaScript and so am wondering if there is something that I am missing (perhaps a hack utilizing some aspect of JavaScript's unintuitive truthiness). There is no errata logged for this in the [book's Errata page](http://www.apress.com/9781590596807). I suspect this is a mistake - but not 100% sure. Is it a broken example?

Comment: You are correct, it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are correct and should notify the author

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I will give some time for any alternative answers to come in. Then, submit the erratum to the publishers.